# Jquery Submit will not do any action

Tags: jquery

I am trying to just make a simple Jquery submit form where the user clicks yes or no to a question and submits the form. And when the form is submitted I will replace the fieldset with the submitted data. But for some reason, nothing happens. I've even tried putting an alert just to see if the code works, but I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;background-color:white;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 20px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color:white;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color:white;}
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//Quiz Submit Button
            $("form").submit( function () {    
                $.ajax({   
                        type: "POST",
                        data : $(this).serialize(),
                        cache: false,  
                        url: "http://www.cwu.edu/~janvik/CS250/echo.php",   
                        success: function(data){
                            alert('it worked');
                            $("fieldset").html(data);                       
                        }   
                    });  return false; 
                });      
</script>

            <h1>Eligibility</h1><hr>
            <h2>Check if you're eligible to vote on the 2014 Referendum?</h2>

<p class="article"><span></span>
<form action="#" onClick='submitDetailsForm()' name="form" class="form" id="form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Eligibility Questionnaire</legend>
        <label id="birthdate">Were you born on or before 18 September 1998?</label></br> 
        <input id="birthdate" type="radio" name="birthdate" value="yes" required="required">Yes</input>
        <input id="birthdate" type="radio" name="birthdate" value="no" required="required">No</input>
        </br></br>
        <label id="birthplace">Are you currently residing in Scotland?</label></br> 
        <input id="birthplace" type="radio" name="birthplace" value="yes" required="required">Yes</input>
        <input id="birthplace" type="radio" name="birthplace" value="no" required="required">No</input>
        </br></br>
        <label id="citizen">Are you a British citizen?</label></br> 
        <input id="citizen" type="radio" name="citizen" value="yes" required="required">Yes</input>
        <input id="citizen" type="radio" name="citizen" value="no" required="required">No</input>
        </br></br>
        <label id="eucitizen">Are you a citizen of the Republic of Ireland and/or other EU countries?</label></br> 
        <input id="eucitizen" type="radio" name="eucitizen" value="yes" required="required">Yes</input>
        <input id="eucitizen" type="radio" name="eucitizen" value="no" required="required">No</input>
        </br></br>
        <label id="eucitizen">Are you a current Service/Crown personnel serving in the UK or overseas in the Armed Forces or with Her Majesty's Government who are registered to vote in Scotland?</label></br> 
        <input id="crownservice" type="radio" name="crownservice" value="yes" required="required">Yes</input>
        <input id="crownservice" type="radio" name="crownservice" value="no" required="required">No</input>
    </fieldset>

    </br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

<div id="results">Test</div>
</p>
```

Comment: Is this file in the same folder as echo.php? check your console f12 > console on chrome

Comment: no, that is why I have to point to it directly on the server. I'll check f12.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you posted the content of echo.php

Comment: I tried the console in chrome, and I received an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } "

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access, I was just told to point my script there for an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

When the script is executed, the <form> element doesn't exists.
Try to put your script inside a $() function, to let it run when everything is loaded:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
            $("form").submit( function () {    
                $.ajax({   
                        type: "POST",
                        data : $(this).serialize(),
                        cache: false,  
                        url: "http://www.cwu.edu/~janvik/CS250/echo.php",   
                        success: function(data){
                            alert('it worked');
                            $("fieldset").html(data);                       
                        }   
                    });  return false; 
                });      
    });
</script>
```

You can also put the script after the declaration of the <form>.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add

$(document).ready(function(){

});

```
<script>
//Quiz Submit Button
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").submit( function () {    
            $.ajax({   
                    type: "POST",
                    data : $(this).serialize(),
                    cache: false,  
                    url: "http://www.cwu.edu/~janvik/CS250/echo.php",   
                    success: function(data){
                        alert('it worked');
                        $("fieldset").html(data);                       
                    }   
                });  return false; 
            });      


});
</script>
```

hope this helps!